# Need to dynamically refresh map in Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I have a working component that does the following:

- receives string from sibling input component via global Bus method in `created()` => **works**
- manipulates string into lat/lng coordinates via `geoDecoding()` => **works**
- resolve promise result coordinates, sets data, also via`geoDecoding()` => **works**
- refresh `showMap()` with changed data after event fired => **does not work** :(

> #### Please note that I have props (commented out) with hardcoded defaults, just to check `showMap()` with those values, and it works.

- I have set a debugger on `showMap()` and i'm noticing that latitude and longitude are not set, which is weird since I set them under `created()` invoking `geoDecoding()`

I would like to have `showMap()` to refresh on every fired event where it would get refreshed data() from `this.latLong.latitude` / `this.latLong.longitude` and re-instantiate the map according to those new values. At this current point and with this code instance pasted here, I am getting `showMap()` to instatiate a map yet map is empty sibce it's not receiving the lat/lng from `geoDecoding()`.

### Code:

```
<template>
    <div class="map-container" :id="theMap"></div>
</template>

<script>
    import { Bus } from "../main";

    export default {
        name: "GoogleMapsContainer",
        data() {
            return {
                theMap: "map-for-" + this.name,
                location: '',
                latLong: {
                    latitude: '',
                    longitude: ''
                },
            }
        },
        props: {
            name,
            // 'latitude': {
            //     type: Number,
            //     default: function () {
            //         return 39.50
            //     }
            // },
            // 'longitude': {
            //     type: Number,
            //     default: function () {
            //         return -98.35
            //     }
            // },
            // 'zoom': {
            //     type: Number,
            //     default: function () {
            //         return 4
            //     }
            // }
        },
        methods: {
            showMap() {
                debugger;
                this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(this.theMap), {
                    center: {lat: this.latLong.latitude, lng: this.latLong.longitude},

                    zoom: this.zoom
                });
            },
            geoDecoding() {
                let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
                let theLocation = this.location;
                let latLong = this.latLong;

                    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
                        geocoder.geocode({'address': (theLocation ? theLocation : 'canada')}, function (results, status) {
                            console.log(results);
                            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                                console.log(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                                latLong.latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                                latLong.longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                            } else {
                                reject(status);
                            }
                        });
                    });
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            //this.geoDecoding();
            this.showMap();

        },
        created() {
            this.geoDecoding();
            Bus.$on('passLocation', (input) => {
                this.location = input;
                this.geoDecoding();
            });
        },


    }
</script>

<style scoped>
    .map-container {
        width: 80vw;
        margin: 5vh auto;
        height: 50vh;
        background: fuchsia;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Could you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? For example, using [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue)

Comment: @MarcoPantaleoni - just get an API key and put it in index.html App.vue really just wraps this component above, and input just `$emit`s an input, nothing special.
You already have a list of stuff that works / doesn't work as listed in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way i've found fit to execute this was with Google's API code:

`panTo(<your-lat-lng-coords>);`

To incorporate this in your code, this would be set during the async call.

My promise is in `methods:{geoDecoding(){}}` as follows:

```
geoDecoding() {
    let geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    let theLocation = this.location;
    let latLong = this.latLong;
    self = this;

    let service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(this.map);
    var erez_markers = [];

    return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        geocoder.geocode({'address': theLocation}, function (results, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                console.log(results[0].geometry.location.lat(), results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                latLong.latitude = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
                latLong.longitude = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
                this.myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(latLong.latitude, latLong.longitude);
                self.map.panTo(this.myLatlng);//******* this would shift map on every instantiation with new lat/lng's
            } else {
                reject(status);
            }
        });
    });
}
```

My state data is set with a default so map would return with something on initialization, as follows:

```
latLong: {
    latitude: 43.6532,
    longitude: -79.3832
},
location: '',
zoom: '',
```

Showing the map would be set globally so we would be able to call/re-instantiate it from any location. I have set it up under `methods:{showmap(){}}`

```
this.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(this.theMap), {
                    center: {lat: this.latLong.latitude, lng: this.latLong.longitude},
                    zoom: this.zoom
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a watcher on `latLong`:

```
  watch: {
    latLong: {
      handler: function(val, oldVal) {
        this.showMap();
      },
      deep: true
    }
  },
```